# SQL Query to Return only one row per customer

Tags: mysql, sql

The database tables I am working with are as the following:

Type_Telephone

| ID_Type_Telephone (PK) | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | LandLine |
| 1 | Cellular |
| 2 | Telecopier |

Telephone

| ID_Telephone (PK) | ID_Client (FK) | ID_Type_Telephone (FK) | Numero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 201 | 0 | 514-555-0165 |
| 101 | 201 | 1 | 514-555-0155 |
| 102 | 202 | 1 | 514-555-0176 |
| 103 | 200 | 0 | 514-555-0164 |
| 104 | 200 | 1 | 514-555-0119 |

Client

| ID_Client (PK) | Nom | Prenom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | Bertrand | Antoine |
| 201 | Legault | Claude |
| 202 | Leonard | Sylvie |

I would like to write a SQL query that lists all customers' Cellular and Landline telephones. I would like to have only one row of results per customer such as:

| Nom | Prenom | Landline | Cellular |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bertrand | Antoine | 514-555-0164 | 514-555-0119 |
| Legault | Claude | 514-555-0165 | 514-555-0155 |
| Leonard | Sylvie |  | 514-555-0176 |

Any advice how to generate this ? Thank you !

Comment: Join 2 copies of `Telephone` to `Client`.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a pivot query, something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    c.ID_Client,
    c.Nom,
    c.Prenom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN tt.Description = 'LandLine' THEN t.Numero END) AS Landline,
    MAX(CASE WHEN tt.Description = 'Cellular' THEN t.Numero END) AS Cellular
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Telephone t
    ON t.ID_Client = c.ID_Client
LEFT JOIN Type_Telephone tt
    ON tt.ID_Type_Telephone = t.ID_Type_Telephone
GROUP BY
    c.ID_Client,
    c.Nom,
    c.Prenom;
```

If you also want to include possible telecopier numbers, then add another max of `CASE` expression to the above query.

Comment: I think we can use `INNER JOIN` instead for better performance.

Comment: @Susang ... Maybe better performance, but it changes the semantics of the answer.  If we use inner join everywhere, then a given person who does not have any phone numbers would be removed from the result set, and most likely the OP doesn't want this.

Comment: You are right if OP wants exactly that :)

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain how this works ? What does the MAX function do ?

Comment: @ZeusofCode The above logic says to take maximum value of `Numero`, but the `CASE` expression generates `NULL` values for any number other than the number type of interest.  And `MAX` ignores `NULL` values, so it just returns the number we want in the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.nom,
       c.prenom,
       t0.numero landline,
       t1.numero cellular
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Telephone t0 ON c.id = t0.ID_Client AND t0.ID_Type_Telephone = 0
LEFT JOIN Telephone t1 ON c.id = t1.ID_Client AND t1.ID_Type_Telephone = 1
```

If you need one more column for `Telecopier` then add one more table copy.

The query assumes that `Telephone (ID_Client, ID_Type_Telephone)` is defined as UNIQUE. If not then

```
SELECT c.nom,
       c.prenom,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t0.numero) landline,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t1.numero) cellular
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Telephone t0 ON c.id = t0.ID_Client AND t0.ID_Type_Telephone = 0
LEFT JOIN Telephone t1 ON c.id = t1.ID_Client AND t1.ID_Type_Telephone = 1
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't you select second number from t1?